# How can I have Rails 4 treat virtual attributes like real ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My model has a `some_date` field and a getter like this:

```
def day
    some_date.day
end
```

Then I have a route: `get 'foo/:day/:id' => 'foo#show', as: 'foo'`.

Now, calling `foo_url(Foo.first)`, leads to **UrlGenerationError ... missing required keys: [:day]** because `Foo.first` just returns `id: 1, some_date: '...'` without including the (virtual) `day` attribute.

**How can I ensure that my virtual attributes are treated like regular ones in such scenarios, and thus make the call to foo_url work?**

Comment: Would it be satisfactory to do `foo_url(Foo.first, day: Foo.first.day)` ? That should work.

Comment: The actual case would require a minimum of four additional attributes to be passed like this on each and every call. That's why I want to avoid this variant.

Comment: If they're all attributes of the same model can't you just have a path that uses :id and retrieve the attributes in the target action?

Comment: Sure, but for semantic purposes I want the data to be present in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) method, i think it is what you need.

> Returns a String, **which Action Pack uses for constructing an URL to
>   this object.** The default implementation returns this record’s id as a
>   String, or nil if this record’s unsaved.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  # overridden
    name
  end
end

user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
user_path(user)  # => "/users/Phusion"
```